# Cannot implicitly convert type <DocAdminPannel.Models.DocMaster>'.An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, linq

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult'
>   to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
public class DoctorController : ApiController
{

    Doctor_infoEntities db = new Doctor_infoEntities();

    public IQueryable<DocMaster> GetDocMasters(string searchString)
    {
        //var Doctor = db.DocMaster.ToList();
        if (searchString == "" || searchString == null)
        {
            return db.DocMaster;
        }
        else
        {
            DocMaster Doctor = db.DocMaster.Find(searchString);
            return Ok(Doctor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or this one [Cannot implicitly convert type. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479911/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-an-explicit-conversion-exists-are-you-missing-a)

Comment: Or this one [Error “an explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast )” comes when creating an object:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837725/error-an-explicit-conversion-exists-are-you-missing-a-cast-comes-when-creat)

Comment: Basically if you'd googled your error you would of gotten lots and lots of answers

Comment: Thankz  guys i will keep this in mind can you please remove minus rateing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method's signature is `IQueryable<DocMaster>`.

Your first return statement returns `IQueryale<DocMaster>` as needed but in the `else` you are returning the result of the `Find` which is a single object and wrapping it with `OK` function which is returning a `System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult` object.

Replace it with something like:

```
return db.DocMaster.Where(item => item.SomeProperty.Contains(searchString));
```

---

*Just a bit of refactoring you can change this line:*

```
if (searchString == "" || searchString == null)
```

*With this:*

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) //Or also string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace
```